# How can I turn live CD running with installed applications into an in-place install

Tags: 18.04, live-cd, persistence

I have a Live CD instance running of the latest Ubuntu with some applications installed and some configurations made. Is there anyway to turn this directly into an in place install?

I'm aware of creating a bootable usb with custom software, but all I'm looking for is turning my current Live CD running now into an installed persistent system. There is currently nothing installed on the system and it is a VM so I don't have access to a USB or burner on it.

Running 18.04 LTS Desktop Live

Answer (score 2):

[Pinguy Builder](http://pinguyos.com/2015/09/pinguy-builder-an-app-to-backupremix-buntu/http://pinguyos.com/2015/09/pinguy-builder-an-app-to-backupremix-buntu/) does that.

> The Pinguy Builder will create a installable ISO of your current system. You can then burn that ISO to a USB using something like Unetbootin or just burn the ISO directly to a DVD. The DVD/USB can then be booted from a PC.
>
> Depending on what option you choose determines what type of ISO gets created.
>   If you pick “Dist”, this will backup the whole system but exclude your home folder and any personal info.
>
> If you pick “Backup”, this will backup the system and will include you home folder (so make sure it isn’t to big).
>
> Both options can run as a live session. “Dist” mode has no password to login. “Backup” mode uses the user name and password used to create the ISO.

You can download it from sourceforge: [Pinguy OS ISO](https://sourceforge.net/projects/pinguy-os/files/ISO_Builder/)

And install it with

```
sudo dpkg -i pinguybuilder_4.3-8_all-beta.deb
```

After the installation, you can use it from the command line with

```
sudo PinguyBuilder backup|clean|dist [cdfs|iso] [filename.iso]
```

Or with the GUI, which has buttons to complete all the available actions.

```
PinguyBuilder-gtk
```